# Excel VBA matching data across 2 sheets. need help repeating the code

Tags: excel, vba, string-matching

My code below pulls first and last names from worksheet 1 and pastes them into worksheet 2 when "White" (meaning martial arts white belt) is listed next to their name and pastes them below the headings at row "x". I need help to repeat this code for the next belt level being "Pro Yellow". The First and last name headings need to be pasted at row 78 and then the names pasted from row 79 down.

```
Sub PastetoAdult()
Dim lr As Long, lr2 As Long, r As Long
Set Sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ADULT members to cut & past")
Set Sh2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ADULT Sign On Sheet")
Sh1.Select

Sh2.Cells(6, 5).Value = "LAST NAME"
Sh2.Cells(6, 6).Value = "FIRST NAME"**
lr = Sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
x = 7
For r = 2 To lr
    If Range("I" & r).Value = "White" Then
        Sh2.Cells(x, 5).Value = Sh1.Cells(r, 2).Value
        Sh2.Cells(x, 6).Value = Sh1.Cells(r, 3).Value
        x = x + 1
    End If

Next r

Sh2.Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Either clone your code in the 'For' loop and modify as needed, or add an 'ElseIf Range("I" & r).Value = "Pro Yellow" Then' and use a different row counter.

Comment: Wayne i have very little coding experience, the Stack exchange community helped me build the current code. Do you have the time to put together your explanation into the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will iterate through each belt color added to the array and place 5 blank lines between each header group.

```
Option Explicit

Sub PastetoAdult()
Dim lr As Long, lr2 As Long, r As Long, x As Long
Dim iBelts As Integer
Dim sBeltColor() As String
Dim Sh1 As Worksheet, Sh2 As Worksheet

Set Sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ADULT members to cut & past")
Set Sh2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ADULT Sign On Sheet")
Sh1.Select

lr = Sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
x = 5   'Start Row

'Load all belt colors into an array via splitting a comma delimited string
sBeltColor() = Split("White,Pro Yellow", ",")

For iBelts = 0 To UBound(sBeltColor)

    'Place belt color as header followed by 'Last Name' & 'First Name' 
    'on the next row with no gap between groups
    Sh2.Cells(x, 5).Value =sBeltColor(iBelts)
    x = x + 1
    Sh2.Cells(x, 5).Value = "LAST NAME"
    Sh2.Cells(x, 6).Value = "FIRST NAME"
    x = x + 1
    For r = 2 To lr
        If Range("I" & r).Value = sBeltColor(iBelts) Then
            Sh2.Cells(x, 5).Value = Sh1.Cells(r, 2).Value
            Sh2.Cells(x, 6).Value = Sh1.Cells(r, 3).Value
            x = x + 1
        End If
    Next r
Next iBelts
Sh2.Select

End Sub
```

Comment: ohh this is some sexy coding you have done here. thanks dustin

Comment: Would it be possible to instead of pasting 5 rows apart, match the belt headings on "adult sign on sheet" for example. E5 says WHITE BELT. then E6:F6 is where first and last names are pasted followed by all white belts.